# Gnuplot - Fitting the key below the plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have been making a clusters of stacked histograms as showed near the bottom of [this page](http://skuld.bmsc.washington.edu/people/merritt/gnuplot/).

I was able to adjust my plot to look like what I wanted but I am struggling with the key. It is quite large so I would like to place it below the plot.

The sensible thing to do seems to be `set key outside below center`

However, it looks like gnuplot is actually centering the second column of the key instead of centering the key as a whole.

[image: current gnuplot result]

My question: how do I go about fixing this ?

Here is my full gnuplot code:

```
set terminal postscript enh color eps font ",18"
set output "SO.eps"

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid border 0
set boxwidth 0.9
set tmargin 2
set bmargin 10
set key outside below center vertical maxrows 4 width -5


set yrange [0:600]
set y2range [0:100]

set xlabel "Number of compute nodes"
set ylabel "Computation Time (s)"
set y2label "Efficiency (%)"
set ytics nomirror
set xtics nomirror
set y2tics 20

plot newhistogram lt 1 , \
"SO.dat" index 0 u 2:xtic(1) title "Warm-Up", \
"" index 0 u 3 title "First program configuration", \
"" index 0 u 4:xtic(1) title "Second configuration", \
"" index 0 u 5 title "Target", \
newhistogram lt 1 , \
"SO.dat" index 1 u 2 notitle, \
"" index 1 u 3 notitle, \
"" index 1 u 4:xtic(1) notitle, \
"" index 1 u 5 notitle, \
newhistogram lt 1 , \
"SO.dat" index 2 u 2 notitle, \
"" index 2 u 3 notitle, \
"" index 2 u 4:xtic(1) notitle, \
"" index 2 u 5 notitle, \
newhistogram lt 1 , \
"SO.dat" index 3 u 2 notitle, \
"" index 3 u 3 notitle, \
"" index 3 u 4:xtic(1) notitle, \
"" index 3 u 5 notitle, \
"SO.dat" index 4 u 1:2 title "First program efficiency" with linespoints axes x1y2, \
"" index 4 u 1:3 title "Second program efficiency" with linespoints axes x1y2, \
"" index 4 u 1:4 title "Target efficiency" with linespoints axes x1y2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A little more fiddling with my script finally gave me the result I wanted.**

*The problem comes from this command:*

set key outside below center vertical maxrows 4 width -5`

It is equivalent to writing:

```
set key outside below
set key vertical maxrows 4 width -5
```

which is different from:

```
set key vertical maxrows 4 width -5
set key outside below
```

**The order matters.** In the first (erroneous) command, the key is placed below the graph in its (default) single column format first, then its layout is changed to two columns. But its original x,y positioning remains the same.

In the second command which gives the desired result, the "two columns" key layout is decided first. Then the key is set below the graph with its *updated* width and is appropriately centered.

[image: Final plot result]